# Could not load credentials from any providers in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, aws-sdk

I am using AWSservices so I am using 'aws-sdk' package for nodeJS. As per their instructions on official website they ask to create a .aws folder in your current user profile and create credentials file there with secrete and access key in it.

AWS doc link -

https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/nodejs/

I follow the same procedure on windows and ubuntu. In windows AWS services are working fine but when I upload my code setup to AWS ubuntu  instance it start giving me following error.

```js
{
  "message": "Missing credentials in config",
  "retryable": false,
  "time": "2019-05-13T12:34:45.834Z",
  "code": "CredentialsError",
  "originalError": {
    "message": "Could not load credentials from any providers",
    "retryable": false,
    "time": "2019-05-13T12:34:45.834Z",
    "code": "CredentialsError"
  }
}
```

Here is code where I include 'aws-sdk' in JS file.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const {
  saveUserTokens,
  updateMigratedUser
} = require('./databaseOperations');

const AWS_REGION = "us-west-2";
const CLIENT_ID = "5f70t79un9ep945645k5rooqocr4mfg";
const USER_POOL_ID = "us-west-2_xxxxx";

AWS.config.update({ region: AWS_REGION });
const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
```

console log of AWS.config object -

```js
Config {
  credentials:
   SharedIniFileCredentials {
     expired: false,
     expireTime: null,
     refreshCallbacks: [],
     accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     sessionToken: undefined,
     filename: undefined,
     profile: 'default',
     disableAssumeRole: true,
     preferStaticCredentials: false,
     tokenCodeFn: null,
     httpOptions: null },
  credentialProvider:
   CredentialProviderChain {
     providers:
      [ [Function],
        [Function],
        [Function],
        [Function],
        [Function],
        [Function] ],
     resolveCallbacks: [] },
  region: 'us-west-2',
  logger: null,
  apiVersions: {},
  apiVersion: null,
  endpoint: undefined,
  httpOptions: { timeout: 120000 },
  maxRetries: undefined,
  maxRedirects: 10,
  paramValidation: true,
  sslEnabled: true,
  s3ForcePathStyle: false,
  s3BucketEndpoint: false,
  s3DisableBodySigning: true,
  computeChecksums: true,
  convertResponseTypes: true,
  correctClockSkew: false,
  customUserAgent: null,
  dynamoDbCrc32: true,
  systemClockOffset: 0,
  signatureVersion: null,
  signatureCache: true,
  retryDelayOptions: {},
  useAccelerateEndpoint: false,
  clientSideMonitoring: false,
  endpointDiscoveryEnabled: false,
  endpointCacheSize: 1000,
  hostPrefixEnabled: true }
```

Comment: Could you please add more details? Also please attach the code that you've used and the directory structure or whatever pertains to this question of yours. And also please explain what is the error that you are encountering.

Comment: Hi I have provide more details...

Comment: Did you create at this location `~/.aws/credentials`?

Comment: yes this file is there

Answer (score 2):

Issue is resolved. I deleted the .aws/credentials. Again create them with **AWS CLI** as a root user. There is two hurdles in this.

First one is  - I am using pm2 to run my node server. It is running multiple instances of a server as a root user as well as with another user profile also.

Second might be related to user access. Still not sure why its not reading credentials from file which is already present there. I have created environment variables also. I already have two providers but still it's not picking keys from them....

Below is the doc link for anyone facing this issue related to providers.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records: We faced the same issue yesterday and had a hard time finding the cause … The configuration in the project and in the `~/.aws/credentials` where correct but we still got the error.

The cause was a **misconfiguration in the `~/.zshrc`**: In the `.zshrc` the environment variable `AWS_PROFILE` was set to an obsolete profile that was no longer present in the `~/.aws/credentials`. So, somehow the value of this `AWS_PROFILE` overwrote the value of the environment variable `AWS_PROFILE` set we defined in our `.env`.

By removing the `AWS_PROFILE` from the `.zshrc` the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Could not load credentials from any providers in NodeJS" can occur for a few reasons. Here are some possible causes and solutions:

You may not have set your AWS credentials in the correct location. The default location for the AWS credentials file is ~/.aws/credentials. You can also set your credentials in environment variables or in a JSON file. See the AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html for more information on how to set your AWS credentials.
Your AWS credentials may be invalid. Make sure that you have entered your access key ID and secret access key correctly. You can also try generating new credentials from the AWS IAM console: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/.
You may not have the necessary permissions to access the AWS resources that you are trying to use. Check the IAM role that you are using to make sure that it has the necessary permissions.
If you have checked all of these things and you are still getting the error message, you can try the following:

Restart your NodeJS application.
Clear your NodeJS cache.

Comment: any AI here?⠀⠀⠀